# How can I layer two JPanels on top of each other?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlayeredpane

I try to layer triangles (JPanel) on top of a map (JPanel). I tried it with a JLayeredPane but the triangle and the map is not layered (see attached picture). In the end, I would like to set a position for a triangle and place it onto the map. I tried to set absolute positions for the triangle and the map with `setBounds()` but it did not work for me. Same result. This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    Container mainContainer;
    JLayeredPane mapLayer;
    BackgroundMap bgMap;
    Mesocyclone meso1;

    public MainFrame() {
        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {
        mainContainer = getContentPane();
        bgMap = new BackgroundMap();
        mapLayer = new JLayeredPane();
        mapLayer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        mainContainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        mainContainer.add(mapLayer);

        meso1 = new Mesocyclone();

        mapLayer.add(bgMap, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
        mapLayer.add(meso1, JLayeredPane.POPUP_LAYER);

        setSize(900, 1000);
        setTitle("Mesodetect | v1.0  \u00A9 ");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;

public class Mesocyclone extends JPanel {
    private static final int PREF_W = 100;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    private static final Color COLOR = Color.RED;
    private Path2D myPath = new Path2D.Double();

    public Mesocyclone() {
        double firstX = (PREF_W / 2.0) * (1 - 1 / Math.sqrt(3));
        double firstY = 3.0 * PREF_H / 4.0;

        myPath.moveTo(firstX, firstY);
        myPath.lineTo(PREF_W - firstX, firstY);
        myPath.lineTo(PREF_W / 2.0, PREF_H / 4.0);
        myPath.closePath();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        // to smooth out the jaggies
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setPaint(COLOR);  // just for fun!
        g2.fill(myPath);  // fill my triangle
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }
}

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class BackgroundMap extends JLabel {
    private Image image;
    private BevelBorder border;

    private int WIDTH = 620;
    private int HEIGHT = 850;

    public BackgroundMap() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("res/map_bg.png"));
            this.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        border = new BevelBorder(1);
        setBorder(border);
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return this.image;
    }
}

import java.awt.*;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: Current State]

Answer (score 0):

```
    mapLayer = new JLayeredPane();
    mapLayer.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    mainContainer.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    mainContainer.add(mapLayer);

    meso1 = new Mesocyclone();

    mapLayer.add(bgMap, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    mapLayer.add(meso1, JLayeredPane.POPUP_LAYER);
```

1. you should not be setting a layout manager for the layered pane. The will cause the components to be displayed in a FlowLayout instead of being layered because the location of each component will be set based on the rules of the FlowLayout. However, if you don't't set the layout manager you are now responsible for setting the size/location of each component you add to the layered pane.
2. Don't use "DEFAULT_LAYER" AND "POPUP_LAYER", those are special layers used by the layered panel. You are just using "regular" layers when you add your own components. So you should be using "new Integer(1)" and "new Integer(2)".

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use LayeredPanes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for a working example of the above two suggestions.

The other option is to not use a layered pane and just use Swings default parent/child relationship between components.

So your image label would become the parent and the triangle component becomes the child. Then your logic would become:

```
JPanel child = new ...
child.setSize( child.getPreferredSize() );
child.setLocation(10, 10);

JLabel parent = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
parent.add( child );
```

Note you would also need to use setOpaque(false) on the child component.

As long as the child component will fit in the bounds of the labels image, this is the easier solution.